# Finding saved image in Android

Tags: android, image, save

I found this code online to save a bitmap to the internal storage in Android, but it seems to not be saving, or I just can't find the image. Where would this save the image, if it were to do so?

```
public boolean saveImageToInternalStorage(Bitmap image) {

    try {
        // Use the compress method on the Bitmap object to write image to
        // the OutputStream
        FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput("desiredFilename.png", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        // Writing the bitmap to the output stream
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        fos.close();

        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("saveToInternalStorage()", e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

see this blog post that explains briefly:

http://rajareddypolam.wordpress.com/?p=3&preview=true

&

try this method:

```
String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");    
myDir.mkdirs();
Random generator = new Random();
int n = 10000;
n = generator.nextInt(n);
String fname = "Image-"+ n +".jpg";
File file = new File (myDir, fname);
if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); 
try {
       FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
       finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
       out.flush();
       out.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and I think what you forgot was the permission to write the image

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Instead of using a random number, I suggest you either use `File.listFiles()` to look for the currently highest number in the filename and increment that, or base the filename on the current time and date (even if it's simply `System.currentTimeMillis()`... although you'd probably want to subtract a big constant). The benefit of doing so is that if a third-party app sorts the filenames, they'll still be in chronological order. Also, there's a (very small) chance that the code you have will clobber an existing file.